# iPython Notebook Markdown Programability for Base Directory

Tags: markdown, jupyter-notebook

I have an iPython notebook with many links to a sharepoint file set within markdown. It is likely that the base location of the files will change at some point in the future. Ideally, I could programatically set the links based on a base directory in anticipation. To explain with an example:

```
[file.pdf](http://collaboration.us.ZZZ/XX/YYY/SDIR1/SDIR2/SDIR3/file.pdf)
```

"http://collaboration.us.ZZZ/XX/YYY/" will likely change in the future and ideally, this could be defined in a variable. There are many links to files located in this base directory. Perhaps a search and replace on the json files is the only option. Is there anything else that I can do in anticipation of the base location changing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the base location relative to where the notebook is hosted ? if so you can use the `file/` prefix for know. Ohterwise I would suggest just displaying HTML in a codecell. 
Programmatically altering markdown is not (yet) possible, but we are thinking of that.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. HTML in a code cell seems like a reasonable compromise. The base location is not relative to the notebook file.